How to format an array of identifiers?
I would like to write a function to define triggers. I would like to call it this way:
CALL make_mutable('mytable', '{"mycolumn3", "mycolumn4"}');

I think I need a dynamic function for this:
CREATE PROCEDURE make_mutable(IN t text, IN cs text[])
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format(
    'CREATE TRIGGER %I
     BEFORE UPDATE ON %I FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE FUNCTION mutable_trigger(%I);',
    concat(t, '_mutable_trigger'), t, cs);
END
$$;

Now I am wondering how to format cs? The format %I takes just one argument but I need to format an array of identifiers.

The function quote_literal seems to work.
CREATE PROCEDURE make_mutable(IN t text, IN cs text[])
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format(
    'CREATE TRIGGER %I
     BEFORE UPDATE ON %I FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE FUNCTION mutable_trigger(%s);',
    concat(t, '_mutable_trigger'), t, quote_literal(cs));
END
$$;

